# Number validation javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, web

my telephone number validation doesn't work and I don't know why.
Submit should be active when number length is 9 or 10,in other case submit should be disabled.Here's the code

HTML body:

```
<body>
<input type="number" name="number-189" value="" class="example1" id="numertel" min="500000000" max="900000000" aria-invalid="false">
<input type="submit" value="Send" class="example" id="przycisk">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

JS

```
var numertell = document.getElementById("numertel");
var numerlength =  numertell.value.length;
if(numerlength==10 && numerlength==9)
  document.getElementById("przycisk").disabled=false;
else
  document.getElementById("przycisk").disabled=true;
```

Comment: What "doesn't work" about it?  How is this code even invoked as the value changes?

Comment: make a working snippet

Comment: `&&` == AND, `||` == OR

Comment: `if(numerlength==10 && numerlength==9)` will always be false. the length can't be 9 AND 10 in the same time. Change it to ||

Comment: That's right,my obvious bad,but id doesn't work too.Submit is always disabled

Comment: @MiKcid: Again, *how is this code being invoked*?  If you're only executing this JavaScript code *once* when the page loads then of course the input is always disabled.  There's no code to ever enable it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Submit should be active when number length is 9 or 10,in other case
>   submit should be disabled

Your problem is this line

```
if(numerlength==10 && numerlength==9)
```

replace `&&` with `||` since `numerlength` **can't be 9 and 10 at the same time**. Check this [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) to know more about logical operators.

```
if( numerlength== 10 || numerlength==9 )
```

**Edit**

You need to invoke the **code** share above when the value of textbox changes. I have shared an example with **keyup** event.

**Demo**

```js
document.getElementById("przycisk").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("numertel").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var numerlength = this.value.length;
  //console.log( numerlength );
  if (numerlength == 10 || numerlength == 9)
    document.getElementById("przycisk").disabled = false;
  else
    document.getElementById("przycisk").disabled = true;
});
```

```html
<input type="number" name="number-189" value="" class="example1" id="numertel" min="500000000" max="900000000" aria-invalid="false">
<input type="submit" value="Send" class="example" id="przycisk">
```

Comment: Maybe explain the difference between `&&` and `||`? Other than that great answer.

Comment: Oh,that's right,but id doesn't work too.Submit is always disabled

Comment: @MiKcid I have added a demo.

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```js
function check_value()
{
var numertell = document.getElementById("numertel");
var numerlength =  numertell.value.length;
if(numerlength == 10 || numerlength ==9)
  document.getElementById("przycisk").disabled=false;
else
  document.getElementById("przycisk").disabled=true;
 }
```

```html
<body>
<input type="number" name="number-189" value="" class="example1" id="numertel" min="500000000" max="9000000000" aria-invalid="false" onblur = "check_value();">
<input type="submit" value="Send" class="example" id="przycisk">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you,that's working,but i'm very curious-can you tell me why my code isn't working?

Comment: the condition of numberlength should be "or" i.e "||"

Answer (score 0):

You should also put that condition inside input event, and assign new numertell value inside that event, like this:

```js
var numertell = document.getElementById("numertel");
var numerlength = numertell.value.length;
if (numerlength === 10 || numerlength === 9)
  document.getElementById("przycisk").disabled = false;
else
  document.getElementById("przycisk").disabled = true;

numertell.addEventListener('input', function(evt) {
  numerlength = numertell.value.length;

  if (numerlength === 10 || numerlength === 9)
    document.getElementById("przycisk").disabled = false;
  else
    document.getElementById("przycisk").disabled = true;
});
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="number" name="number-189" value="" class="example1" id="numertel" min="500000000" max="900000000" aria-invalid="false">
  <input type="submit" value="Send" class="example" id="przycisk">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

html >>>

```
<body>
<input type="number" name="number-189" value="1234" class="example1" id="numertel" min="500000000" max="900000000" aria-invalid="false" onkeydown="myFunction()">
<input type="submit" value="Send" class="example" id="przycisk" >
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

javascript >>>

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 myFunction();
});
function myFunction() {
     var numertell = document.getElementById("numertel");
  var numerlength =  numertell.value.length;
  if(numerlength==10 || numerlength==9)
    document.getElementById("przycisk").disabled=false;
  else
   document.getElementById("przycisk").disabled=true;
}
```

Comment: There is no indication from the user that they are using jQuery so there is no point in using jQuery's document ready when there are javascript only options.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

`if(numerlength === 10 || numerlength === 9)`.

`||` is an operator for 'OR' operation in Javascript. Also for comparison should use `===` rather than `==`.